# LCD rows not all lighting up

Tags: lcd

I'm wondering if I've blown my lcd by accident. It's supposed to be a 20 * 4 rows lcd however only row 2 and row 4 seem to light up. Should they not all light up

Comment: By 'light up', do you mean you see black squares? Your LCD probably has 2 controllers, as unixbigot said. And you might have it upside down :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some four-row LCDs are actually two controllers with separate enable inputs.

Try writing to all the locations in the data RAM, the memory-address to character-location in these LCDs is not always what you think it is.   For example I have a weird 16x1 display that is actually laid out as two disjoint 8-column memory ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Check your programming and connections. I doubt that you could damage module in such way that only two rows which aren't close together remain functioning.

Comment: but the weird thing is it does it without the avr as well.

Comment: @Ageis Maybe it is not initialized? They often are half-lit when not initialized. I don't know about 4 rows, but I have had 1 (half of the line lit up) and 2 (other line lit up) line displays.